# Buy new domain, how remove already indexed pages?

Tags: seo, domains

I buy a old domain name and I am going to start new blog on it.

Currently, it has more than 100 pages indexed by Google.

How to remove all of them before start my site?

Comment: You don't. You cannot influence search engines. Just create your new website and it will change in time. Just make sure the old pages/URLs give a proper 404 error.

Comment: You don't need to worry about them. Google will remove them automatically in time.

Answer (score 1):

1.list all indexed page and put their url in disallow list.
2.additionally for all such page, create a 410 status( page have deleted permanently)

3.Go to webmaster tools and remove from index( all unwanted indexed pages)

3rd process is manual process. This will take a lot of time to deindex.

Apply all 3 process and continue working on new content.